# Using CloneState in VB.Net - RateExpense.CloneState is not cloning rate lists

Tags: .net, vb.net

```
Protected Overrides Function CloneState() As IRateExpense
Dim RateExpense As IRateExpense = New RateExpense(True)
RateExpense.RateLoad = Me.RateLoad
RateExpense.RateBase = Me.RateBase
RateExpense.RateAdjustmentList = Me.RateAdjustmentList
Return RateExpense
End Function
```

The issue is in `RateExpense.RateAdjustmentList = Me.RateAdjustmentList`, where `RateExpense.CloneState` is not cloning RateAdjustmentList (rate lists). The `RateExpense.RateAdjustmentList` is populated with previous RateLoad.

Comment: What are RateLoad, RateBase and RateAdjustementList? If they are references to objects you are not clonining anything but just copying the references.

Comment: Yes, these are object references. While RateLoad, RateBase are correctly cloned, RateAdjustementList is not. The expected behaviour is this list should be populated with current RateLoad not the previous ones.

Comment: If they are object references they are not cloned, but copied. In other words you are just copying the address where this data is kept, so you have two references to the same memory area. I suggest you to search about values and references type as well the differences between deep copy and swallow copy

Comment: Thanks Steve, i think the issue to my problem is both the RateExpense and its memento are pointing to the same list of RateAdjustmentList. Besides this i would like to know how this CloneState and its memento works.